# How to return a reference in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm using `Vector3D` structure. I encounter a situation that if I have a property like:

```
Vector3D MyVec {get; set;}
```

If I call `MyVec.Normalize();` the `MyVec` value is not modified. I know struct is value type and the getter will shallow copy a new instance and return it, so the `Normalize()` method will modified the temp object not `MyVec` itself.

1. How can I solve this situation? `Vector3D` is struct not class and I cannot modify this.
2. Can I return the reference in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assign the created struct

```
MyVec = MyVec.Normalize();
```

As devio pointed out, if the Normalize method doesn't return a new struct (mutable struct is evil), here is your solution :

```
var myVec = MyVec;
myVec.Normalize();
MyVec = myVec;
```

Comment: if you are referring to this Normalize() method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.normalize.aspx this won't work

Comment: This won't work because `Normalize()` doesn't return a result at all, it works inplace. Mutable structs are evil, but we have a mutable struct here and need to work around it I suppose :(

Answer (score 1):

A ref to a struct would result in unsafe code in .Net.

Two solutions come to mind:

- Allow manipulation of the Vector3D struct only via the classes containing such struct properties.
- Encapsulate Vector3D struct in a separate class and have this class pass through all struct methods as you require

  ```
  public class Vector3DProxy
  {
      Vector3D value;

      public Vector3D Value { get ... set ... }

      public void Normalize() { value.Normalize(); }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Method can accept reference to value type.

```
public void Normalize(ref YourStruct pParameter)
{
//some code change pParameter
}

Normalize(ref someParameter);
```

Similar works and out operator: only difference, when use out pParameter can be not initialized(assigned).

Edit: But it's usable only if you have control to method, else simple assign value.

Comment: You mean: Normalize(ref someObject.PropertyA)? Yes, it won't work. I think compiller will give warning (or event compillation error).

Answer (score 0):

I think you only may solve this like this;

```
MyVec = MyVec.NormalizeVector();


public static class Extension
{
    public static Vector3D NormalizeVector(this Vector3D vec)
    {
        vec.Normalize();
        return vec;
    }
}
```